# Ruby on Windows Command Prompt

Tags: ruby

I am brand new to Ruby, and I have downloaded and installed it and added Ruby to my PATH.

I opened a new command prompt and typed `Ruby`, which put me into a session so to speak.

I then started to type various commands like, `help`, `update`, `version` etc and it did nothing.

I then tried `exit`, `quit` and `cancel` only to find that you have to use `CTRL+C` to interrupt.

Anyways, did I harm the installation in any way by typing in those random commands? I never received any feedback after I typed the commands, just dropped a new line.

Comment: Use `irb` to open an interactive console.

Answer (score 2):

ruby is the compiler I believe.  irb is the interactive console.

If you do `Ruby myRubyFile.rb` it will run the file for you.  This is useful in a batch script i have found.

for example if the ruby script renames some files and moves them somewhere you can put that in a bat or bash shell script.

Comment: If you enter the `EOF` character after inputting commands instead of `Ctrl+C` (is it Ctrl+D in Windows?) you'll see that it actually runs the program at that point.

Answer (score 1):

When you type

ruby

like that, you're pointing the Ruby interepreter at . . . nothing!

Make a file called hello_world.rb, and put this line into it:

puts "Hello, world!"

Then type

ruby hello_world.rb

and see what happens.